# Load test websocket server?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, load-testing

## IDEA

I have a websocket server I'd like to determine:

- max concurrent connections
- any errors

## Testing

As far as I know, to get this job done, I need a decent websocket test suite. I've so far only attempted to use [Thor](https://github.com/observing/thor). But it doesn't allow me to send extra data.

## Problem

The websocket server requires a token for a connection, hence why Thor doesn't work out of the box, I need a way to send a token with the test software. I'd like to keep this part in the test, as it has to authenticate to another machine, and hence would not be a true load test if I remove that part.

**code for the tornado server.py file:**

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
def check_origin(self, origin):
    return True

def open(self, *args):
    self.id = self.get_argument("id")
    accessToken = self.get_argument("accessToken")
    #print "socket opened id: %s
    self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
    addActive(accessToken)
    clients[self.id] = {"id": self.id, "accessToken":accessToken, "object": self}
```

Any thoughts on a test suite or method to get Thor working?

Answer (score 0):

When I had to perform load testing of a WebSocket application I used [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for it. It doesn't support WebSocket out of box, however it is possible via [plugin](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) or some Java coding.

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for approaches and instructions on how to do it with JMeter